# Артефакты на графическом интерфейсе Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

При отладке нагрузочных тестов GUI версия JMeter начала выдавать артефакты в виде ряби и задвоения интерфейса. Пробовал установить последнюю версию и предыдущие версии, менял разрешение монитора, но ничего не помогает. На другом компьютере работает нормально[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте обновить JDK до [17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download#openjdk-17) или [21](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download#openjdk-21), тем более что по возможности рекомендуется [использовать последние версии JMeter и Java](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling)
2. Попробуйте задать [параметры JVM отвечающие за графику](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#d3d) например `sun.java2d.d3d` и `sun.java2d.opengl` в `true` или `false`
3. Если ничего не помогает стоит [завести тикет в проекте](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Comment: 1) Стоит 17 JDK 2)Не помогло 3) Надо попробовать